# OnBlur and OnSelect Both events getting called in prime ng calendar control Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am using prime ng calendar control and for time picker.but when I am selecting any time both the onBlur and Onselect events are getting called.Please help to resolve.Here is the code I have use:

```
 <p-calendar id="endtime" name="end" [stepMinute]="15" (onSelect)="onEndTimeChange()" (onBlur)="onEndTimeChange()" [(ngModel)]="searchParameters.endTime" class="form-control time-control"
        showTime=true timeOnly=true placeholder="End Time">
      </p-calendar>
```

[Time picker control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hlZI.png)

Comment: What is the issue? Do you need different functionality for blur vs select? Can you just choose either select or blur to execute `onEndTimeChange()`? Why do you have both assigned?

Comment: Issue is when i select something for first tie in time picker both the blur and select event gets called.

Comment: As i want to performed one operation on time change so i have assigned onblur as well as on select the same method.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just not understanding the issue. It sounds like if you just use onSelect or onBlur, not both, then `onEndTimeChange()` will only be executed a single (1) time. Maybe update your question to provide more detail on what happens `onEndTimeChange()` and the exact serious of events you are seeing. I'd also recommend to maybe create a working example with [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or similar. Thanks!

Comment: hi bro, did you find the solution? I'm also facing the same issue. I'm using version 11 of primeng. Looks like they have solved this problem in newer versions but i cannot upgrade to new versions. Please help.